# Creating AD SPNs with realmd/sssd on Cent7

Tags: active-directory, sssd, rhel7, spn

Is it possible to use the system tools provided by realmd/sssd on a CentOS7 system to create and write out service principals for Apache and other servers?  Or are we still reliant on other tools, like samba-tool and setspn.exe?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is. The preset-computer command comes the closest, but I'd still use the Samba tools.

btw adcli does no magic underneath, it still mostly calls the samba utilities as well.